# Array.push performs deep copy instead of shallow copy

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular

**Context**

I'm using Typescript/Angular2 RC1 for my webapp and I have two classes. In class1 (Angular2 service), I have a variable `myVar = [obj1, obj2, obj3]` and in class2 (Angular2 component), I get `myLocalVar = class1.myVar` in the constructor using `viewInjector` to inject the service.

**Problem**

In class2, I copy `myVar` with a `push` (shallow copy because it copies objects) so `myLocalVar` is equal to `[obj1, obj2, obj3]` (such that `objX={number:X}`). When I change one item such as: `myVar[0]={number:5}` in class1 the change won't appear in my class2 `myLocalVar` and `myLocalVar[0].number` will be equal to `1`. However, `myVar` of class2 changes... It seems that the `this.myLocalVar.push(this.myVar[int]);` created a deep copy instead of a shallow copy.

Is Typescript changing the behavior of a `push` in Javascript? If yes, what should I do to keep the reference and do a shallow copy?

**Code Sample**

```
@Injectable()

export class Class1{

    public myVar:any[];

    constructor(){
        this.myVar = [{number: 1}, {number: 2}, {number: 3}];
    }

    changeVar(newVar):void{
        this.myVar[0] = newVar; // newVar = {number: 5}
    }
}
```

---

```
@Component({
    selector: 'class2',
    viewInjector: [Class1],
    templateUrl: 'someURL'
})
export class Class2{

    private myLocalVar:any[] = [];

    constructor(class1: Class1){
        this.myVar = class1.myVar;
    }

    showVars():void{
        console.log(this.myLocalVar[0]);
        console.log(this.myVar[0]);
    }

    ngOnInit(){
        for(let int = 0; int < this.myVar.length; int++){
            this.myLocalVar.push(this.myVar[int]);
        }
    }
}
```

The `console.log` will print two different values: `console.log(this.myLocalVar[0])` prints `1` and `console.log(this.myVar[0]);` prints `5` after `changeVar()` has been called by a third party!

**Edit**

Here is a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/Ofnw3OVSMgHJEFWnwzTu?p=preview) that demonstrates the problem:

- Click on show, check your console and you will see the same values
- Click on change
- Click on show again and you will see two different values for `myVar` and `myLocalVar`

What I need is each time I change `myVar[x]=newObj` I want `myLocalVar` to reflect that change. Please include a solution to that problem if you want your answer to be validated.

Comment: I think your mistake is thinking that `push` creates copy. You can easily push the same object reference to numerous arrays. Try using `angular.copy()` if you need a copy

Comment: @charlietfl I know `push` does a shallow copy but it seems that in this case it does a deep copy! Otherwise, why do I get two different values?

Comment: I have never seen `Array.protoype.push` make copy. I'm not up on typescript but doubt it does anything different with `Array`. `var a=[], b=[], d={foo:'bar'}` then push `d` into `a` and `d` into `b` and change property in either and will be inherited by the other since they are both references to same object

Comment: @charlietfl maybe the problem is angular 2 then...but I can't believe it would affect such a basic property of javascript

Comment: Create a simple demo that replicates issue. I doubt angular2 overloads `Array.push` either that would be mind numbing to developers and so against good practices

Comment: In this example `myLocalVar = ` is missing, and `{number 3}` is syntax error and who knows what else. `push` doesn't create a deep copy. I would suggest to seek the problem elsewhere.

Comment: @charlietfl please see my plunker (just edited my question)

Comment: @estus thanks for the syntax errors but please focus on the problem rather than syntax... see my plunker!

Comment: So what should i look for in plunker?

Comment: @charlietfl only class1 and class2... click on show first (check your console you will see same values) then click on change and show again. You will see that it prints two different values!

Comment: "I know push does a shallow copy" --- it does not do any copies.

Comment: @zerkms I meant point to reference... please see my plunker, you will understand what I mean!

Comment: You are overwriting the whole object not changing it's properties   `this.myVar[0] = {number:newVar};` is not the same as  `this.myVar[0].number=newVar`. That's why you think it's a copy but you are breaking the original reference completely

Comment: @charlietfl yes but I need to overwrite the object (my object is deep and has many changes)... what can I do then?

Comment: Use `angular.extend()` instead or `angular.merge()` if you don't want to break reference

Comment: And get rid of the idea that push does any kind of copy .... it doesn't

Comment: @charlietfl Well, what I want is to keep the reference in `myLocalVar` so it also changes to `5`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113238/discussion-between-ncohen-and-charlietfl).

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
ngOnInit(){
    for(let int = 0; int < this.myVar.length; int++){
        this.myLocalVar.push(this.myVar[int]);
    }
}
```

to

```
ngOnInit(){
  this.myLocalVar = this.myVar;
}
```

In the first only reference of the array elements is copied. In the second reference of array is getting copied?

Comment: I can't do that...my real scenario is that I filter some objects

Answer (score 0):

Your intent seems to be to update an object's values, but instead you are creating a new object and inserting that new object into the original array (only).

This will do what you intended:

```
changeVar(newVar: Object): void {
    this.myVar[0].number = newVar.number;
}
```

The plunker code you linked to is not in sync with the posted code.  In the plunker's case, you are passing a number, not an object.  It has:

```
changeVar(newVar): void {
    this.myVar[0] = {number:newVar}; // newVar = {number: 5}
}
```

In that case, change to:

```
changeVar(newVar: number): void {
    this.myVar[0].number = newVar;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

"Object.assign" does the shallow copy.

```
(<any>Object).assign(this.shallowCopyObject, this.myObject);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your have this problem because `myLocalVar` and `myVar` are two different references. Meaning, they are **two different array containers**.

And when you push element from `myVar` to `myLocalVar`, you push the references of the elements in `myVar` into `myLocalVar`. So 
if

`myVar = [{name: 1}, {name: 2}]` you have two object in it and both references to the objects are pushed into `myLocalVar`.

When you call `changeVar` method, you basically replace the element reference in `myVar` with new object reference. However, the old reference to the element being replaced is still there and referenced by `myLocalVar`, thus the result you see.

So the solution?

You need to change how your `changeVar` method set the value. Instead of doing `this.myVar[0] = {number:newVar};`, you should do `this.myVar[0]['number'] = newVar;` This maintains the reference.